# Problem with equation numbering, resets after ten

Tags: equations, numbering

i have a problem with my thesis, equation numbering resets after number 10. For example, in the doc after equation 3.3.10 follows 3.3.1 and not 3.3.11.
Here is my preamble

```
   \documentclass[12pt,A4,twoside]{book}
%Φορτώνονται τα πακέτα
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\nogreekalph
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Ανοίγει τη βιβλιοθήκη για την εισαγωγή γραφικών
\input{epsf.tex}

% Το πακέτο για το ευρετήριο(-index)
\usepackage{makeidx}
% Για να φτιάξουμε στο τέλος του αρχείο Index
\makeindex



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%H \renewcommand ξαναορίζει κάποιες ήδη υπάρχουσες εντολές
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\contentsname{\sc Περιεχόμενα}
\renewcommand\bibname{\sc Βιβλιογραφία}
\renewcommand\indexname{Ευρετήριο}
\renewcommand\figurename{Σχήματα}
\renewcommand\tablename{Πίνακες}
\renewcommand\chaptername{{\sc Κεφάλαιο}}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Παράρτημα}
\newtheorem{defn}{\noindent \underline{\sc Oρισμός}}
\newtheorem{definition}{\noindent \underline{\sc Definition}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\noindent \underline{\sc Theorem}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{\noindent \underline{\sc Πρόταση}}
\newtheorem{thm}{\noindent \underline{\sc Θεώρημα}}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\noindent \underline{\sc Λήμμα}}
\newtheorem{ineq}{\noindent \sc Ανισότητα}
\newcommand{\defset}[3]{\ensuremath{\left\{\, #1\in #2\; :\;
#3\,\right\}}\xspace}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\addtocounter{defn}{1}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\addtocounter{defn}{1}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\addtocounter{defn}{1}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\theineq}{\addtocounter{defn}{1}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
%\setcounter{defn}{0}
%\setcounter{thm}{0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\tr}{\text{tr}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Επιλέγουμε το style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} \pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase
\fancyhf{} %delete the current section for header and footer
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sc \small\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sc \small{\chaptername} \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\newcommand{\en}{\text}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
% make space for the rule

% Ορίζει το πλάτος της σελίδας (γραμμένου κειμένου) σε cm ή in
%\textwidth=15.5cm  % 6.0in
% Ορίζει το μήκος της σελίδας (γραμμένου κειμένου) σε cm ή in
\textheight=22.5cm % 8.0in
% Ορίζουν το  πού να αρχίζει  η σελίδας σε cm
\evensidemargin = -0.6cm %δεξιό κενό
\oddsidemargin = -0.0cm  %αριστερό κενό
% Ορίζει το paragraph indentation
%\parindent=0.cm
% Ορίζει το separation between par.
%\parskip=0.1cm
%\tolerance=10000 %\brokenpenalty=10000
\headheight 0cm %πάνω κενό
%\footheight 15pt %κάτω κενό
% Ορίζει την απόσταση μεταξύ των γραμμών.
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}  % Όμοια \def\baselinestretch{1.4}
\headsep = 1cm \topmargin = 1cm  \voffset = -0.8cm \footskip =
1.6cm
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, some code showing the problem, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why all these redefinitions of the basic counters?

Comment: The `\the<counter>` should not contain assignments as incrementing a counter. This is asking for trouble. Examples: The counter could be referenced and references should not change the counter. Or `hyperref` breaks, if the macro `\the<counter>` is used in anchor names. For a better solution, see package `aliascnt` for instance.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Can you make an answer?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek New ping!

Comment: @egreg I have made an answer, however, it does not explain the unexpected reset of the `equation` counter.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is both too long (unnecessary stuff) and too short, it does not show the problem, the reset of the equation number, when it reaches 10.

Therefore this answer addresses some other problems.

- The macro `\the<counter>` defines the appearance of the counter value. It should/must not contain assignments and changes of the counter value:

  - The `\addtocounter` then also goes into the references. Each time `\ref` is called on such a reference, the counter is increased.
  - Package `hyperref` uses the `\the<counter>` for anchor names and does not like unexpandable stuff like assignments.

  Package `amsthm` supports shared counters for theorem definitions, e.g.:

  ```
  \newtheorem{lemma}[defn]{...}
  ```

  A lemma will use the counter `defn` instead of an own one.
  See the example below.
- Package `graphicx` is loaded, thus an explicit loading of `graphics` is not necessary, since it willalready be loaded by `graphicx`. But `\input{epsf.tex}` is very deprecated old stuff, that should be removed.
- Class/global option `A4` is unrecognized. Class `book` knows `a4paper` instead.
- `\fancyhead` is used, but `\headheight` is set to zero.

Example for shared counters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{defn}{\noindent \underline{Defn}}
\newtheorem{proposition}[defn]{\noindent \underline{\sc Proposition}}
\newtheorem{thm}[defn]{\noindent \underline{\sc Thm}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[defn]{\noindent \underline{\sc Lemma}}
\newtheorem{ineq}[defn]{\noindent \sc Ineq}

\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}
\renewcommand{\theineq}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{defn}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
\begin{defn} Definition 1 \end{defn}
\begin{lemma} Lemma 1 \end{lemma}
\begin{lemma} Lemma 2 \end{lemma}
\begin{defn} Definition 2 \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]